# Xcode: Multiple CoreData models per each target

Tags: ios, core-data, targets

I am working on a project which contains multiple targets. This project is using CoreData but each target's needs are different enough to where I thought it would be useful to have a separate Core Data models (eg. `TargetName.xcdatamodeld`) for each target. And all models would share a common entity with the same class file. I would like to know if any other developers have used this pattern?

Comment: have u able to do this?

Comment: @George are you able to do this ?